# How to add B2C to MAUI?

Tags: azure, authentication, maui, azure-ad-b2c, policies

I'm tring to add B2C to my MAUI app but still not working. The official tutorial on Microsoft page is not using any policies, and I haven't found yet how to add and use sign up sign in, edit profile and modify password policies.

The solution on Microsoft hadn't even worked for Android for me. It had some kind of issues with not defining the start activity. Also tried this solution: https://youtu.be/gQoqg4P-uJ0

But got errors:

for Android I get: You must subclass the `WebAuthenticatorCallbackActivity` and create an IntentFilter for it which matches your `callbackUrl`.

and for windows: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll.

Comment: Please read [ask] before posting